# Jquery change() method does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to set a date in a one input text field of my html page and then call a script once the date is set and assign a new date value to an another text field. New date value is calculated using the first date value.
I  use `$("#id").change()` for that. But it does not work as I expected. This is my code for that.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my file</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

        <!-- Load jQuery JS -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS  -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#firstDate,#lastDate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#firstDate").change(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var initialDate = ("#firstDate").val();
                    var totDate = initialDate;
                    var dateArray = totDate.split("-");

                    var dateObj = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1] - 1, dateArray[0]);
                    dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 14);
                    totDate = (dateObj.getDate() + 14) + "-" + dateObj.getMonth() + "-" + dateObj.getFullYear();
                    alert(totDate);
                    $("#lastDate").val(totDate);

                });
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            first date: <input type="text" id="firstDate"/>
            last date: <input type="text" id="lastDate" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have put prevent default to stop the page is getting scrolled to top once the script is called(This is a part of a big html page).
Why this does not work properly. Can you explain me why doesn't this work and a way to overcome the issue.

Comment: missing `$` in `("#firstDate").val()`... should be `$("#firstDate").val()` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w52jtxLb/1/

Comment: see my answer below.... it is actually much more simpler if you use the proper api methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in your script is the missing `$` as I said in my comment...

But I would change the implementation to use the [datepicker api](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) methods

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#firstDate").change(function(event) {
    var dateObj = $("#firstDate").datepicker('getDate');
    dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 14);
    $("#lastDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dateObj));

  });
});
$(function() {
  $("#firstDate,#lastDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  first date: <input type="text" id="firstDate"/>
  last date: <input type="text" id="lastDate" />
</div>
```